# Unable to parse plist in Cocos2dx 3.0

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

[image]

I want to parse this plist structure...Please help

What I am using right now is

```
mainDictionary = __Dictionary::createWithContentsOfFile(plistPath.c_str());
__Dictionary *exit = (__Dictionary*)__Dictionary::createWithDictionary(
            (__Dictionary*)mainDictionary->objectForKey(std::string("otherButton")));
```

But there are keys missing exit dictioanry...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In 3.0+ version the data structure like CCDictionary CCArray are deprecated. You have to use **ValueMap** or **ValueVector** etc
You can find the data structure under the folder ValueVector > **CCValue.h**

Here's the code for reading this plist:

```
cocos2d::ValueMap gameData;
gameData = FileUtils::getInstance()->getValueMapFromFile("data.plist");
```

In case you want to read the values:

```
//1
std::string backgroundValue = gameData.at("background");

//2
ValueMap otherButtonsMap = gameData.at("otherButton").asValueMap();
std::string tagValue = otherButtonsMap.at("Tag");

//3
ValueVector buttonsVector = gameData.at("Buttons").asValueVector();
ValueMap item0 = buttonsVector.at(0).asValueMap();
```

Where the gameData is ValueMap (or in other words Dictionary or Map or HashMap)

**Edit:**

The answer by "Wez Sie Tato" is correct but in your case you should read the plist in ValueMap instead of ValueVector, because your plist is actually the Dictionary(ValueMap) and not the Array(ValueVector).

Answer (score 1):

Try use ValueMap and FileUtils to load PList file. The way you try to load dictionary is from cocos2d-x v2.x. In cocos2d-x you should do something like this:

```
ValueMap mainDictionary = FileUtils::getInstance()->getValueMapFromFile(plistPath.c_str());

ValueMap exit = mainDictionary["otherButton"].asValueMap();
```

Comment: No viable overloaded operator[] for type 'ValueVector' (aka 'vector<cocos2d::Value>') getting this error & for mainDictionary its giving size =0

Comment: I made mistake when copy this lines from my project where I'm use ValueVector :) Now is ok.

Answer (score 0):

There is simply no key named "ExitButton" in the root of the plist (and thus in `mainDictionary`).

The `mainDictionary` keys will be "background", "otherButton" and "Buttons", each returning another Dictionary or Array instance.

If the "ExitButton" key is somewhere in the Buttons array, you have to enumerate the Buttons array and find the "ExitButton" key in one of the array items.

Comment: I have edited the question. I know what u r saying but I need the syntax since I am iOS developer from UIKit. Since I parse dictionary , it gives only one key though there r many